# Post command works in terminal but does not work in javascript command

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I run this post via curl in terminal. My test function works great. I see the name I pass as a parameter in the response inside my test lambda function. But getting it working through terminal is not my end goal unfortunately.

```
    curl -v -X POST 'https://miyyxihee3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/EchoTest' -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
"callerName": "Name!"
}'
```

I'm looking to call this url and post data through it via javascript. My issue is that I get a CORS related error when I attempt to make a POST call on the javascript. More specifically, the error is:
`Failed to load https://miyyxihee3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/EchoTest: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here is what I have tried in my javascript code:

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://miyyxihee3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/EchoTest");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({callerName:"Name!"}));
```

P.S. I'm new to javascript. I have been poking my head in some CORS documentation. From my understanding, CORS needs specific headers to accommodate the post request? I have CORS enabled inside my AWS API gateway. A bit confused why it works in the terminal but not in javascript. Can someone kindly help?

Comment: CORS needs to be set on the server. Not in the POST request. In your case, it basicly means that the server allowes POST requests cross origin (from another server and/or domain).

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it working. I added that header in the lambda function. Thanks!